# Why does OWLViz only display "is-a" relationship?

Tags: visualization, ontology, protege

Is is possible to display other properties, i.e. "hasTopping" etc.?

How to do that in OWLViz?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

OWLViz **only** display the class hierarchies (both asserted and inferred class hierarchy). which is described using only "is-a" relationships.

[OWLVizGuide](http://cs.tju.edu.cn/faculty/rgz/new/KE2016/%E5%AE%9E%E9%AA%8C%E4%B8%80/OWLVizGuide.pdf)

Other properties may be displayed using the [OWLPropViz](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/OWLPropViz) plugin.

[List of visualisation tools for Protégé](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Visualization)

This [paper](ftp://ftp.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pub/library/medoc.ustuttgart_fi/FACH-0205/FACH-0205.pdf) compare and evaluate some ontology visualisation tools.